# How to remove a child from a Progress object?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

The Progress object has `addChild(_:withPendingUnitCount:)` method but seemingly no way to remove a child progress object, nor does the child progress object seem to be automatically removed after it's completed.  I want to be able to "reset" my Progress object if all of the children have reached completion.   Otherwise, it seems that it holds on to the children forever and they will affect the calculation of fractionCompleted.  Is there any way to reuse a Progress object in this way?  It's desirable because it's being observed by an app-wide UIProgressView.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. You have to create a new Progress each time. You could set up a Property Observer for when the object changes and reset your UIProgressView progress at that time.

```
var progChanged: ((Progress?) -> Void)?
var downloadProgress: Progress? {
    willSet {
        progChanged?(newValue)
    }
}
```

You can find more information here from Vince Spader's WWDC 2015 talk ["Best Practices for Progress Reporting"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/232/).

> Once they're done, they're done. Once they're canceled, they're canceled. If you need to reuse an NSProgress, instead make a new instance and provide a mechanism so the client of your progress knows that the object has been replaced, like a notification.